# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: in symfony

Tags: symfony, insert, symfony-forms

I am doing a project in Symfony. For inserting an article I have set these variables :

```
 $article->setCategoryId($category_id);
 $article->setName($name);
 $article->setContent($description);
 $article->setStatus($publicity);
 $article->setCreatedOn(new \DateTime());
 $article->setCreatedBy($user->getId());
 //print_r($article); die;
 $em->persist($article);
 $em->flush();
```

When i try to print the `$article` object I am getting the `category_id` value just fine. But as I try to save it, it returns an error like:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null"

This is the setter in my entity:

```
/**
 * Set categoryId
 *
 * @param integer $categoryId
 *
 * @return HelpCenterArticle
 */
public function setCategoryId($categoryId)
{
    $this->categoryId = $categoryId;

    return $this;
}
```

This is my entity when doing `print_r($article)`:

```
lpCenterBundle\Entity\HelpCenterArticle Object
(
    [id:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\HelpCenterArticle:private] => 
    [name:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\HelpCenterArticle:private] => fbfdb
    [slug:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\HelpCenterArticle:private] => 
    [content:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\HelpCenterArticle:private] =>  fbdsbf 
    [categoryId:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\HelpCenterArticle:private] => 4
    [createdOn:HelpCenterBundle\Entity\HelpCenterArticle:private] => 
        DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2018-06-11 09:58:32
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/London
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you show us the categoryId property in your entity ?

Comment: /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $categoryId;

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straightforward

```
$article->setCategoryId($category_id);
```

parameter **$category_id** is null or empty

if you wish to set null value then update ORM **category**

```
nullable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare nullable in your entity

```
nullable=true
```

In entity

```
 /**
  * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
  */
 private $categoryId;
```

Comment: Then validate the category_id field using @Assert